# How to integrate less into Create React App without ejecting

Tags: reactjs, less, create-react-app

I've tried `react-app-rewire-less` module, but it doesn't work.

react-app-rewire-less-modules but it returns error after install

Comment: One thing you can do is fork the react-scripts repo and publish your own version. You get all the benefits of Create React App (regular updates, bug fixes, etc) and you can modify webpack however you fancy. (We have a production app using this very method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-app-rewire-less works.
My problem was that I import "name.less" instead of "./name.less";

UPD
Also for them who are looking for solution - you can use craco

Answer (score 0):

CRA has a [documentation for integrating SASS](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc) in to it. You can pretty much change SASS tools there to LESS to achieve what you want.

Here's what I did:

I installed `less` and `less-watch-compiler`

```
yarn add less less-watch-compiler
```

Then add this line to scripts in package.json

```
"scripts": {
"watch-css": "less-watch-compiler src/ ./",
"start": "react-scripts start",
```

Now when running

```
yarn watch-css
```

When I make a change in `src/App.less`, corresponding `src/App.css` is generated.